# TypeORM multiple columns in IN clause

Tags: typeorm

In mysql,

```sql
select * from table where (column1, column2) IN (('1', '1'), ('2', '2'))
```

How can I use this in TypeORM.

I tried do this:

Like

```
const conditions = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2')];
QueryBuilder
  .where(`(column1, column2) IN (${conditions.join(',')})`)
```

But this is not a good way, is there a better solution?